# Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates when rendering component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, ecmascript-6

I've been trying to render a component using map, the render happens but with a warning:

> Warning: unstable_flushDiscreteUpdates: Cannot flush updates when
> React is already rendering.

MyBooks.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ActionAreaCard from '../components/ActionAreaCard';

const MyBooks = ({address}) => {

    const [metadata, setMetadata] = useState([]);

    const URL = `http://localhost:3001/api/tatumapi`;
    const chain = 'CELO';
    const params = { address: address, chain: chain };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(URL,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(params)
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setMetadata(
              (data.data).map((data2) => {
                return data2.metadata.map((data3) => {
                  return data3;
                })
              })
            ))
    }, [])

    return (
      <div>
        {metadata.map((data4) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {data4.map(({metadata}) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    {metadata!= null && console.log(metadata)}
                    {metadata!=null && <ActionAreaCard name={metadata.name} description={metadata.description} image={metadata.image}/>}
                  </div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
}

export default MyBooks;
```

Console output:

```
{description: 'The very first edition', name: 'BOOK', image: 'ipfs://bafkreidny67q3xxjulstouk7vzp6bomdbnokg3zzhg6k4gqbdtutqzz5h4'}
description: "The very first edition"
image: "ipfs://bafkreidny67q3xxjulstouk7vzp6bomdbnokg3zzhg6k4gqbdtutqzz5h4"
name: "BOOK"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Why I'm getting this warning and how can I solved it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just improved the mapping and added a key.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ActionAreaCard from '../components/ActionAreaCard';

const MyBooks = ({address}) => {
  
    const [metadata, setMetadata] = useState([]);

    const URL = `http://localhost:3001/api/tatumapi`;
    const chain = 'CELO';
    const params = { address: address, chain: chain };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(URL,
            {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(params)
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setMetadata(data.data.map(data2 => {
              return data2;
            })))
    }, [])
    
    return(
      <div>
        {metadata!=undefined && metadata!=null && metadata.map((data) => {
          return data.metadata.map(({metadata}, i) => {
            return (
              <div key={i}>
                {metadata!==null && <ActionAreaCard name={metadata.name} description={metadata.description} image={metadata.image}/>}
              </div>
            )
          })
        })}
      </div>
    )
}

export default MyBooks;
```